# SVNサーバーの構築方法を知りたい

Tags: svn

文系大学からIT業界に進んだ者です。

社内で新部署が作られ、そこでSVNの導入を行おうとしています。
SVNの導入方法を調査するように上司に言われました。
色々見ているのですが、知識不足のためよくわかりません。

トータスSVNだけでは、使用出来なそうな雰囲気を感じました。
SVNサーバー構築の方法を知りたいと思っています。
Apacheやsvnserveというサーバー側のソフトがあるのは理解しました。(あっているかは分かりません。)
サーバー構築する為のわかりやすいサイト、もしくはSVNサーバーの構築のやり方など、ご教示お願いできますでしょうか。

補足-検証を行うので、一旦マシンはHPのノートPCで、OSはWin11になります。

Comment: 今どき `SVN` ですか？できれば `git` にしましょう。絶対にそのほうが使いやすいし将来性とか発展性とかがあります。なぜ今更 `subversion` なのか問い詰めたほうがよさそうな。

Comment: 僕もそう思い、比較表や事例出してgitを勧めたのですが、決定したのと、sesで派遣されている有名な企業なので、svnから変わることはないです。svnでわかることがありましたら教えてください。

Comment: サーバとしてどんなマシンどんな OS を使うかは決まっていますか？　その辺がわからないと解説しようがないです。元質問の編集という形でその辺の追記をしてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。補足として追記したのですが、情報足りますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

`git`と`SVN`を比較検討できるほどの知識と能力がある方ならば、有名どころのツールを採用して運用できそうな予感がします。
例えば[`Apache SVN`](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html)を取得してコンソールから`svnadmin create`でリポジトリを作成して、Windowsなら[`sc create svnserve`](https://www.ipentec.com/document/subversion-svnserve)でサービス化し、Linuxなら[`svnserve.service`](https://qiita.com/OmeletteCurry19/items/c47b861dc563919c94ac)でサービス化することができます。
枯れまくっているので`Apache SVN`と`TortoiseSVN`の最新版を使えば相性問題なども起こりにくいはずです。

楽に構築して保守画面をGUIで扱いたいならば[VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/)を使う方法もあります。
インストールウィザードをポチポチするだけで簡単に構築できます。

さてスタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！
[「subversion サーバ構築」](https://www.google.com/search?q=subversion+%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89)で検索をかけると大量のサイトがヒットしますが、色々見ている中でこのようなサイトをご覧になったでしょうか。
サイトやツールのお勧めを尋ねるいわゆる[買い物リスト質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381)は回答の幅が広くなるので敬遠されがちです。
具体的に何が分からないのか、調査のどこで困っているのかなどを明確にすると求める回答を得やすくなります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。初めて使用しましたので、今後の使用時に活かしていこうと思います。ご教示ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`subversion` は集中リポジトリ型なので、サーバ上にソースコードリポジトリが１つだけある構成です。そのため、サーバ上のリポジトリが壊れると一切合切全てが失われることになります。なのでバックアップ（それもオフラインにできるバックアップ）ができる体制は絶対必要です。 Windows 11 のノート PC でサーバを立てること自体は簡単ですが、それを実運用にて使うことは全くもって推奨できません。オイラが管理者なら絶対拒否します。
# Windows 11 Pro あたりをサーバ利用するのは EULA 違反です（たぶん）
# Windows Server の価格が組織運用面で出せます？

いまどきは `subversion` クラウドサービスを利用することをお勧めしたいです。わざわざオンプレミスに D2T できるサーバ立てて管理者つけて維持するコストと比べると、絶対安価な気がします。が、それが上司なり派遣先なりに認められるかは別問題っス。もうちょっと先方と条件を詰めてから検討したほうがよさそう。

で、どこをお勧めしますか？　とかは買い物リスト質問ですし広告になっちゃいますし，今この時点では書けないっス。

---

検証ってのは実運用に可能な限り近いもので行わないと意味がないです。ノート PC で簡易な検証をして使えそう→実サーバは全く異なるものになってしまって使い方すらわからない、では掛けたコストが全部無駄になってしまいます。

まずはオンプレかクラウドかあたりから決めましょう（決定権がある人に決めてもらいましょう）検証はそのあと。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。運用の方法など諸々含めて、一度上司と打ち合わせを行なってみます。再度Gitの提案もしてみます。